# What products, if any, have ever been recalled by LEGO?

Tags: history, safety, discontinued

The question says it all. Have there ever been any recalls of products by LEGO? If so, what were they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [a list of recalls dating back to 2002](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/product-recalls) on the LEGO site, so that's a start.

It contains two items:

- A specific version of the IR remote, typically used for trains.
- A one piece toy truck, only sold in the USA.